# ggplot2: NA's introduced when creating Boxplot legend values

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a plot I'm trying to create where the x axis is time and the y axis is a continuous variable.  Boxplots are drawn grouped by day and time of day within day.  The legend shows the time of day grouping.  I then overlay a smoothed curve over points with different curves for the time of day.  Now, if I leave the x axis as a factor and then use some selective indexing for the breaks, I get the following plot using the following code:

```
ggplot( x10NoOutliers , aes( factor( ExecutionDate ) , Concentration ) ) +
   geom_boxplot( aes( fill = TimeOfDay ) , outlier.colour = "blue" ) +
   geom_smooth( aes( group = TimeOfDay , colour = TimeOfDay ) ) +
   opts( axis.text.x = theme_text( size = 8 , angle = -90 , hjust = 0 ) ) +
   scale_x_discrete(breaks = factor(levels(factor(x10NoOutliers$ExecutionDate))
     [seq( 1 , length(levels(factor(x10NoOutliers$ExecutionDate))), 4 )])) + 
   opts( title = "Boxplot of Concentration by Execution Date and Time of Day", 
         ylab = expression( "Concentration,"~frac( "ng" , mu*"l" ) ) , 
         xlab = "Execution Date" )
```

[image: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7202/6962370691_e984dd9d31_m.jpg]

When I try to get sophisticated and use scale_x_date for the x axis, I get two odd things happening.  I get NA's introduced into the legend for the boxplot (there are no NA's in the data set) and the boxplot groupings are not done correctly.

Here's the code and an example of the plot:

```
qplot( iExecutionDate , Concentration, data = x10NoOutliers, geom = "boxplot", 
       group = factor( ExecutionDate ) , fill = TimeOfDay , 
       outlier.colour = "blue" ) + 
    geom_smooth( aes( group = TimeOfDay , colour = TimeOfDay ) ) + 
    opts( title = "Boxplot of Concentration by Execution Date and Time of Day",
           ylab = expression( "Concentration,"~frac( "ng" , mu*"l" ) ) , 
          axis.text.x = theme_text( size = 7 , angle = -90 , hjust = 0 ) ) +
    scale_x_datetime( major = "1 week" , minor = "1 day" , 
                     name = "Execution Date" , format = "%d-%b-%Y" )
```

[image]

Anyone have any idea why 1) the NA's are introduced into the legend, and 2) why the groupings are not performed correctly?

I've tried a couple of variations on the code above with no progress toward the right outcome.

Thanks!!

Dave H

Here's a copy of the data:

```
"Concentration","ExecutionDate","iExecutionDate","pExecutionDate","TimeOfDay"
8,2011-05-19,2011-05-19 12:00:00,2011-05-18 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-11-29,2010-11-29 12:00:00,2010-11-28 16:00:00,"AM"
7.5,2010-11-19,2010-11-19 12:00:00,2010-11-18 16:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-12-16,2010-12-16 12:00:00,2010-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-02-16,2011-02-16 12:00:00,2011-02-15 16:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2010-11-19,2010-11-19 12:00:00,2010-11-18 16:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-11-10,2010-11-10 12:00:00,2010-11-09 16:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2010-09-16,2010-09-16 12:00:00,2010-09-15 17:00:00,"MID"
7.5,2010-11-09,2010-11-09 12:00:00,2010-11-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-11-08,2010-11-08 12:00:00,2010-11-07 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-10-14,2010-10-14 12:00:00,2010-10-13 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2010-11-05,2010-11-05 12:00:00,2010-11-04 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-11-04,2010-11-04 12:00:00,2010-11-03 17:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2010-11-02,2010-11-02 12:00:00,2010-11-01 17:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"PM"
8.2,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2010-09-16,2010-09-16 12:00:00,2010-09-15 17:00:00,"MID"
8.8,2010-09-16,2010-09-16 12:00:00,2010-09-15 17:00:00,"MID"
8.4,2010-09-13,2010-09-13 12:00:00,2010-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
8.5,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"PM"
8,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8,2010-09-13,2010-09-13 12:00:00,2010-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
7.6,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
7.5,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"PM"
8.4,2010-09-13,2010-09-13 12:00:00,2010-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
8.3,2010-09-13,2010-09-13 12:00:00,2010-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
7.2,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"PM"
8.2,2010-10-20,2010-10-20 12:00:00,2010-10-19 17:00:00,"MID"
7.7,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-09-13,2010-09-13 12:00:00,2010-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
8.6,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8.9,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8.5,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-10-28,2010-10-28 12:00:00,2010-10-27 17:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"PM"
8.3,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2010-09-10,2010-09-10 12:00:00,2010-09-09 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2010-10-27,2010-10-27 12:00:00,2010-10-26 17:00:00,"MID"
7.7,2010-10-13,2010-10-13 12:00:00,2010-10-12 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-09-10,2010-09-10 12:00:00,2010-09-09 17:00:00,"AM"
7.7,2010-10-20,2010-10-20 12:00:00,2010-10-19 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"MID"
8.8,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-10-27,2010-10-27 12:00:00,2010-10-26 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2010-10-19,2010-10-19 12:00:00,2010-10-18 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2010-09-10,2010-09-10 12:00:00,2010-09-09 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"MID"
7.7,2010-10-11,2010-10-11 12:00:00,2010-10-10 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2010-09-16,2010-09-16 12:00:00,2010-09-15 17:00:00,"MID"
8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"MID"
8.9,2010-10-18,2010-10-18 12:00:00,2010-10-17 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2010-10-08,2010-10-08 12:00:00,2010-10-07 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8.5,2010-10-08,2010-10-08 12:00:00,2010-10-07 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-09-10,2010-09-10 12:00:00,2010-09-09 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-10-20,2010-10-20 12:00:00,2010-10-19 17:00:00,"MID"
9.3,2010-10-07,2010-10-07 12:00:00,2010-10-06 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
9.1,2010-10-27,2010-10-27 12:00:00,2010-10-26 17:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8.7,2010-09-17,2010-09-17 12:00:00,2010-09-16 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-09-10,2010-09-10 12:00:00,2010-09-09 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2010-10-26,2010-10-26 12:00:00,2010-10-25 17:00:00,"MID"
8.7,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"MID"
7.9,2010-09-15,2010-09-15 12:00:00,2010-09-14 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-06-09,2011-06-09 12:00:00,2011-06-08 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2010-09-14,2010-09-14 12:00:00,2010-09-13 17:00:00,"MID"
9.4,2010-10-25,2010-10-25 12:00:00,2010-10-24 17:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-10-15,2010-10-15 12:00:00,2010-10-14 17:00:00,"AM"
9.6,2010-10-06,2010-10-06 12:00:00,2010-10-05 17:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2010-09-16,2010-09-16 12:00:00,2010-09-15 17:00:00,"MID"
9,2010-10-06,2010-10-06 12:00:00,2010-10-05 17:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2010-10-20,2010-10-20 12:00:00,2010-10-19 17:00:00,"MID"
9.7,2011-08-04,2011-08-04 12:00:00,2011-08-03 17:00:00,"MID"
8.4,2011-04-13,2011-04-13 12:00:00,2011-04-12 17:00:00,"AM"
7.5,2011-04-12,2011-04-12 12:00:00,2011-04-11 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-08-30,2011-08-30 12:00:00,2011-08-29 17:00:00,"MID"
8.6,2011-07-19,2011-07-19 12:00:00,2011-07-18 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-06-08,2011-06-08 12:00:00,2011-06-07 17:00:00,"AM"
10.4,2011-06-28,2011-06-28 12:00:00,2011-06-27 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-01-05,2011-01-05 12:00:00,2011-01-04 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-03-04,2011-03-04 12:00:00,2011-03-03 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-03-03,2011-03-03 12:00:00,2011-03-02 16:00:00,"MID"
8.8,2011-02-16,2011-02-16 12:00:00,2011-02-15 16:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-12-08,2010-12-08 12:00:00,2010-12-07 16:00:00,"MID"
7.6,2011-03-09,2011-03-09 12:00:00,2011-03-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-03-03,2011-03-03 12:00:00,2011-03-02 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-12-16,2010-12-16 12:00:00,2010-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-04-05,2011-04-05 12:00:00,2011-04-04 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-03-03,2011-03-03 12:00:00,2011-03-02 16:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-02-14,2011-02-14 12:00:00,2011-02-13 16:00:00,"MID"
8.3,2011-03-02,2011-03-02 12:00:00,2011-03-01 16:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2010-12-16,2010-12-16 12:00:00,2010-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-02-04,2011-02-04 12:00:00,2011-02-03 16:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-01-28,2011-01-28 12:00:00,2011-01-27 16:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-04-04,2011-04-04 12:00:00,2011-04-03 17:00:00,"MID"
8.5,2010-12-08,2010-12-08 12:00:00,2010-12-07 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-01-25,2011-01-25 12:00:00,2011-01-24 16:00:00,"MID"
9.3,2010-12-07,2010-12-07 12:00:00,2010-12-06 16:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2010-12-06,2010-12-06 12:00:00,2010-12-05 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2010-12-15,2010-12-15 12:00:00,2010-12-14 16:00:00,"AM"
7.7,2011-03-02,2011-03-02 12:00:00,2011-03-01 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-03-01,2011-03-01 12:00:00,2011-02-28 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-12-06,2010-12-06 12:00:00,2010-12-05 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2010-11-24,2010-11-24 12:00:00,2010-11-23 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-04-04,2011-04-04 12:00:00,2011-04-03 17:00:00,"AM"
7.7,2011-03-31,2011-03-31 12:00:00,2011-03-30 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-03-15,2011-03-15 12:00:00,2011-03-14 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-01-25,2011-01-25 12:00:00,2011-01-24 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-12-02,2010-12-02 12:00:00,2010-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-03-30,2011-03-30 12:00:00,2011-03-29 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-03-09,2011-03-09 12:00:00,2011-03-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-01-03,2011-01-03 12:00:00,2011-01-02 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-12-02,2010-12-02 12:00:00,2010-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-12-29,2010-12-29 12:00:00,2010-12-28 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-03-28,2011-03-28 12:00:00,2011-03-27 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-03-21,2011-03-21 12:00:00,2011-03-20 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-03-18,2011-03-18 12:00:00,2011-03-17 17:00:00,"MID"
8.6,2010-12-27,2010-12-27 12:00:00,2010-12-26 16:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2010-11-24,2010-11-24 12:00:00,2010-11-23 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-11-19,2010-11-19 12:00:00,2010-11-18 16:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-01-24,2011-01-24 12:00:00,2011-01-23 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-02-28,2011-02-28 12:00:00,2011-02-27 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-12-22,2010-12-22 12:00:00,2010-12-21 16:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-03-11,2011-03-11 12:00:00,2011-03-10 16:00:00,"PM"
7.6,2011-03-18,2011-03-18 12:00:00,2011-03-17 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-03-08,2011-03-08 12:00:00,2011-03-07 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-01-21,2011-01-21 12:00:00,2011-01-20 16:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2011-01-20,2011-01-20 12:00:00,2011-01-19 16:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-03-17,2011-03-17 12:00:00,2011-03-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-03-11,2011-03-11 12:00:00,2011-03-10 16:00:00,"MID"
8.6,2010-12-21,2010-12-21 12:00:00,2010-12-20 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-03-08,2011-03-08 12:00:00,2011-03-07 16:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2011-03-07,2011-03-07 12:00:00,2011-03-06 16:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-11-10,2010-11-10 12:00:00,2010-11-09 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-11-19,2010-11-19 12:00:00,2010-11-18 16:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-11-29,2010-11-29 12:00:00,2010-11-28 16:00:00,"MID"
8.4,2010-11-16,2010-11-16 12:00:00,2010-11-15 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-03-16,2011-03-16 12:00:00,2011-03-15 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-02-21,2011-02-21 12:00:00,2011-02-20 16:00:00,"AM"
9,2010-12-14,2010-12-14 12:00:00,2010-12-13 16:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-03-15,2011-03-15 12:00:00,2011-03-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8,2010-12-10,2010-12-10 12:00:00,2010-12-09 16:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-01-18,2011-01-18 12:00:00,2011-01-17 16:00:00,"MID"
8.8,2011-02-18,2011-02-18 12:00:00,2011-02-17 16:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-03-07,2011-03-07 12:00:00,2011-03-06 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-01-18,2011-01-18 12:00:00,2011-01-17 16:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2010-12-09,2010-12-09 12:00:00,2010-12-08 16:00:00,"PM"
8.7,2011-01-10,2011-01-10 12:00:00,2011-01-09 16:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2010-12-01,2010-12-01 12:00:00,2010-11-30 16:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-11-19,2010-11-19 12:00:00,2010-11-18 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-11-09,2010-11-09 12:00:00,2010-11-08 16:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2010-11-29,2010-11-29 12:00:00,2010-11-28 16:00:00,"AM"
7,2010-11-17,2010-11-17 12:00:00,2010-11-16 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-01-07,2011-01-07 12:00:00,2011-01-06 16:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2010-12-21,2010-12-21 12:00:00,2010-12-20 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-01-06,2011-01-06 12:00:00,2011-01-05 16:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2011-03-07,2011-03-07 12:00:00,2011-03-06 16:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2010-12-20,2010-12-20 12:00:00,2010-12-19 16:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-03-11,2011-03-11 12:00:00,2011-03-10 16:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-03-10,2011-03-10 12:00:00,2011-03-09 16:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2010-12-17,2010-12-17 12:00:00,2010-12-16 16:00:00,"PM"
8.6,2010-12-01,2010-12-01 12:00:00,2010-11-30 16:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-03-04,2011-03-04 12:00:00,2011-03-03 16:00:00,"AM"
7.3,2011-03-10,2011-03-10 12:00:00,2011-03-09 16:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2010-12-09,2010-12-09 12:00:00,2010-12-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-03-09,2011-03-09 12:00:00,2011-03-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-07-18,2011-07-18 12:00:00,2011-07-17 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-08-04,2011-08-04 12:00:00,2011-08-03 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-06-03,2011-06-03 12:00:00,2011-06-02 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-08-04,2011-08-04 12:00:00,2011-08-03 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-11-12,2010-11-12 12:00:00,2010-11-11 16:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2010-11-11,2010-11-11 12:00:00,2010-11-10 16:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2010-12-01,2010-12-01 12:00:00,2010-11-30 16:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2010-12-17,2010-12-17 12:00:00,2010-12-16 16:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2010-12-09,2010-12-09 12:00:00,2010-12-08 16:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-06-03,2011-06-03 12:00:00,2011-06-02 17:00:00,"AM"
7.3,2011-08-18,2011-08-18 12:00:00,2011-08-17 17:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-08-17,2011-08-17 12:00:00,2011-08-16 17:00:00,"MID"
8.2,2011-06-28,2011-06-28 12:00:00,2011-06-27 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-09-01,2011-09-01 12:00:00,2011-08-31 17:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-08-11,2011-08-11 12:00:00,2011-08-10 17:00:00,"MID"
8.6,2011-05-13,2011-05-13 12:00:00,2011-05-12 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-06-02,2011-06-02 12:00:00,2011-06-01 17:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-06-02,2011-06-02 12:00:00,2011-06-01 17:00:00,"AM"
11.8,2011-08-29,2011-08-29 12:00:00,2011-08-28 17:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-08-29,2011-08-29 12:00:00,2011-08-28 17:00:00,"AM"
8.5,2011-04-11,2011-04-11 12:00:00,2011-04-10 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-08-26,2011-08-26 12:00:00,2011-08-25 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-07-15,2011-07-15 12:00:00,2011-07-14 17:00:00,"AM"
7.6,2011-05-11,2011-05-11 12:00:00,2011-05-10 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-07-15,2011-07-15 12:00:00,2011-07-14 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-08-03,2011-08-03 12:00:00,2011-08-02 17:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-07-14,2011-07-14 12:00:00,2011-07-13 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-08-25,2011-08-25 12:00:00,2011-08-24 17:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2011-08-25,2011-08-25 12:00:00,2011-08-24 17:00:00,"AM"
11.6,2011-08-09,2011-08-09 12:00:00,2011-08-08 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-06-27,2011-06-27 12:00:00,2011-06-26 17:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2011-08-03,2011-08-03 12:00:00,2011-08-02 17:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-06-23,2011-06-23 12:00:00,2011-06-22 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2011-07-13,2011-07-13 12:00:00,2011-07-12 17:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-07-12,2011-07-12 12:00:00,2011-07-11 17:00:00,"AM"
8.1,2011-08-02,2011-08-02 12:00:00,2011-08-01 17:00:00,"AM"
8.4,2011-06-22,2011-06-22 12:00:00,2011-06-21 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-05-10,2011-05-10 12:00:00,2011-05-09 17:00:00,"AM"
7.5,2011-06-01,2011-06-01 12:00:00,2011-05-31 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-07-27,2011-07-27 12:00:00,2011-07-26 17:00:00,"AM"
7.4,2011-05-09,2011-05-09 12:00:00,2011-05-08 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-07-11,2011-07-11 12:00:00,2011-07-10 17:00:00,"MID"
7.1,2011-05-04,2011-05-04 12:00:00,2011-05-03 17:00:00,"AM"
8.2,2011-06-01,2011-06-01 12:00:00,2011-05-31 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-05-26,2011-05-26 12:00:00,2011-05-25 17:00:00,"AM"
8.6,2011-09-13,2011-09-13 12:00:00,2011-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
7.8,2011-07-27,2011-07-27 12:00:00,2011-07-26 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-08-25,2011-08-25 12:00:00,2011-08-24 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-06-22,2011-06-22 12:00:00,2011-06-21 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-05-04,2011-05-04 12:00:00,2011-05-03 17:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-08-19,2011-08-19 12:00:00,2011-08-18 17:00:00,"AM"
7.5,2011-08-08,2011-08-08 12:00:00,2011-08-07 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-07-26,2011-07-26 12:00:00,2011-07-25 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-06-17,2011-06-17 12:00:00,2011-06-16 17:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-07-25,2011-07-25 12:00:00,2011-07-24 17:00:00,"MID"
8.1,2011-07-08,2011-07-08 12:00:00,2011-07-07 17:00:00,"AM"
8.3,2011-05-25,2011-05-25 12:00:00,2011-05-24 17:00:00,"AM"
7.9,2011-05-03,2011-05-03 12:00:00,2011-05-02 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-04-29,2011-04-29 12:00:00,2011-04-28 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-08-08,2011-08-08 12:00:00,2011-08-07 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-04-18,2011-04-18 12:00:00,2011-04-17 17:00:00,"AM"
8.7,2011-04-15,2011-04-15 12:00:00,2011-04-14 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-06-16,2011-06-16 12:00:00,2011-06-15 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-07-25,2011-07-25 12:00:00,2011-07-24 17:00:00,"AM"
9,2011-04-14,2011-04-14 12:00:00,2011-04-13 17:00:00,"AM"
8,2011-07-06,2011-07-06 12:00:00,2011-07-05 17:00:00,"MID"
9,2011-06-15,2011-06-15 12:00:00,2011-06-14 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-07-22,2011-07-22 12:00:00,2011-07-21 17:00:00,"MID"
8,2011-09-12,2011-09-12 12:00:00,2011-09-11 17:00:00,"MID"
10.1,2011-07-05,2011-07-05 12:00:00,2011-07-04 17:00:00,"AM"
7.8,2011-07-21,2011-07-21 12:00:00,2011-07-20 17:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-07-19,2011-07-19 12:00:00,2011-07-18 17:00:00,"MID"
9,2011-06-10,2011-06-10 12:00:00,2011-06-09 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-06-30,2011-06-30 12:00:00,2011-06-29 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-09-12,2011-09-12 12:00:00,2011-09-11 17:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-09-09,2011-09-09 12:00:00,2011-09-08 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-11-23,2011-11-23 12:00:00,2011-11-22 16:00:00,"AM"
9.6,2012-01-25,2012-01-25 12:00:00,2012-01-24 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2012-01-27,2012-01-27 12:00:00,2012-01-26 16:00:00,"MID"
9.8,2011-09-26,2011-09-26 12:00:00,2011-09-25 17:00:00,"PM"
9.2,2011-12-02,2011-12-02 12:00:00,2011-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-11-21,2011-11-21 12:00:00,2011-11-20 16:00:00,"AM"
10.5,2011-11-18,2011-11-18 12:00:00,2011-11-17 16:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-11-07,2011-11-07 12:00:00,2011-11-06 16:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-10-19,2011-10-19 12:00:00,2011-10-18 17:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-09-22,2011-09-22 12:00:00,2011-09-21 17:00:00,"AM"
9.6,2011-11-04,2011-11-04 12:00:00,2011-11-03 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-11-29,2011-11-29 12:00:00,2011-11-28 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-09-27,2011-09-27 12:00:00,2011-09-26 17:00:00,"AM"
10.3,2011-10-27,2011-10-27 12:00:00,2011-10-26 17:00:00,"MID"
9.6,2011-09-26,2011-09-26 12:00:00,2011-09-25 17:00:00,"PM"
9.8,2012-01-18,2012-01-18 12:00:00,2012-01-17 16:00:00,"MID"
9.5,2011-11-04,2011-11-04 12:00:00,2011-11-03 17:00:00,"MID"
8.9,2011-09-26,2011-09-26 12:00:00,2011-09-25 17:00:00,"PM"
10.4,2011-10-28,2011-10-28 12:00:00,2011-10-27 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-11-09,2011-11-09 12:00:00,2011-11-08 16:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-12-09,2011-12-09 12:00:00,2011-12-08 16:00:00,"MID"
10.3,2011-11-23,2011-11-23 12:00:00,2011-11-22 16:00:00,"MID"
9.4,2012-01-12,2012-01-12 12:00:00,2012-01-11 16:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2011-10-26,2011-10-26 12:00:00,2011-10-25 17:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2011-10-25,2011-10-25 12:00:00,2011-10-24 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-09-15,2011-09-15 12:00:00,2011-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
10.6,2011-12-14,2011-12-14 12:00:00,2011-12-13 16:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-12-20,2011-12-20 12:00:00,2011-12-19 16:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-10-17,2011-10-17 12:00:00,2011-10-16 17:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-12-08,2011-12-08 12:00:00,2011-12-07 16:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-11-23,2011-11-23 12:00:00,2011-11-22 16:00:00,"MID"
9.2,2011-09-29,2011-09-29 12:00:00,2011-09-28 17:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-10-31,2011-10-31 12:00:00,2011-10-30 17:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-11-17,2011-11-17 12:00:00,2011-11-16 16:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-09-27,2011-09-27 12:00:00,2011-09-26 17:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-10-20,2011-10-20 12:00:00,2011-10-19 17:00:00,"AM"
9.6,2011-10-26,2011-10-26 12:00:00,2011-10-25 17:00:00,"AM"
10.3,2011-10-14,2011-10-14 12:00:00,2011-10-13 17:00:00,"MID"
9,2011-10-12,2011-10-12 12:00:00,2011-10-11 17:00:00,"MID"
10.6,2011-11-29,2011-11-29 12:00:00,2011-11-28 16:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-10-25,2011-10-25 12:00:00,2011-10-24 17:00:00,"AM"
10.7,2011-11-07,2011-11-07 12:00:00,2011-11-06 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-11-07,2011-11-07 12:00:00,2011-11-06 16:00:00,"MID"
13,2011-10-25,2011-10-25 12:00:00,2011-10-24 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-11-03,2011-11-03 12:00:00,2011-11-02 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-12-12,2011-12-12 12:00:00,2011-12-11 16:00:00,"AM"
10.1,2011-09-20,2011-09-20 12:00:00,2011-09-19 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2012-01-06,2012-01-06 12:00:00,2012-01-05 16:00:00,"AM"
9.3,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"PM"
10.5,2011-10-18,2011-10-18 12:00:00,2011-10-17 17:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2011-12-16,2011-12-16 12:00:00,2011-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-09-22,2011-09-22 12:00:00,2011-09-21 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-11-28,2011-11-28 12:00:00,2011-11-27 16:00:00,"AM"
10.5,2011-11-28,2011-11-28 12:00:00,2011-11-27 16:00:00,"MID"
10.5,2011-11-22,2011-11-22 12:00:00,2011-11-21 16:00:00,"AM"
9,2011-12-05,2011-12-05 12:00:00,2011-12-04 16:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-12-22,2011-12-22 12:00:00,2011-12-21 16:00:00,"AM"
10.3,2011-10-27,2011-10-27 12:00:00,2011-10-26 17:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-10-18,2011-10-18 12:00:00,2011-10-17 17:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-09-29,2011-09-29 12:00:00,2011-09-28 17:00:00,"AM"
10.6,2011-10-17,2011-10-17 12:00:00,2011-10-16 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-09-19,2011-09-19 12:00:00,2011-09-18 17:00:00,"MID"
9.3,2011-09-22,2011-09-22 12:00:00,2011-09-21 17:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2011-11-30,2011-11-30 12:00:00,2011-11-29 16:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-10-14,2011-10-14 12:00:00,2011-10-13 17:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-11-10,2011-11-10 12:00:00,2011-11-09 16:00:00,"MID"
10.9,2011-09-28,2011-09-28 12:00:00,2011-09-27 17:00:00,"AM"
11.5,2011-09-28,2011-09-28 12:00:00,2011-09-27 17:00:00,"AM"
9.1,2011-09-21,2011-09-21 12:00:00,2011-09-20 17:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-10-20,2011-10-20 12:00:00,2011-10-19 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-09-15,2011-09-15 12:00:00,2011-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
8.7,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"MID"
9.9,2011-09-22,2011-09-22 12:00:00,2011-09-21 17:00:00,"AM"
8.9,2011-10-25,2011-10-25 12:00:00,2011-10-24 17:00:00,"AM"
10.7,2011-11-22,2011-11-22 12:00:00,2011-11-21 16:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-10-17,2011-10-17 12:00:00,2011-10-16 17:00:00,"MID"
9.7,2011-11-03,2011-11-03 12:00:00,2011-11-02 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-09-15,2011-09-15 12:00:00,2011-09-14 17:00:00,"MID"
9.7,2011-09-27,2011-09-27 12:00:00,2011-09-26 17:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2011-10-18,2011-10-18 12:00:00,2011-10-17 17:00:00,"AM"
9.2,2011-12-13,2011-12-13 12:00:00,2011-12-12 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-11-02,2011-11-02 12:00:00,2011-11-01 17:00:00,"MID"
11,2011-10-26,2011-10-26 12:00:00,2011-10-25 17:00:00,"AM"
8.8,2011-12-06,2011-12-06 12:00:00,2011-12-05 16:00:00,"MID"
9.6,2011-11-18,2011-11-18 12:00:00,2011-11-17 16:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.4,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.6,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.1,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
9.4,2011-12-30,2011-12-30 12:00:00,2011-12-29 16:00:00,"AM"
9,2011-09-13,2011-09-13 12:00:00,2011-09-12 17:00:00,"MID"
10.7,2011-09-28,2011-09-28 12:00:00,2011-09-27 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-11-21,2011-11-21 12:00:00,2011-11-20 16:00:00,"MID"
9,2011-12-21,2011-12-21 12:00:00,2011-12-20 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-11-30,2011-11-30 12:00:00,2011-11-29 16:00:00,"MID"
10.2,2011-10-21,2011-10-21 12:00:00,2011-10-20 17:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-10-28,2011-10-28 12:00:00,2011-10-27 17:00:00,"AM"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.2,2011-10-27,2011-10-27 12:00:00,2011-10-26 17:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-11-15,2011-11-15 12:00:00,2011-11-14 16:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-11-08,2011-11-08 12:00:00,2011-11-07 16:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
9.7,2011-11-16,2011-11-16 12:00:00,2011-11-15 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.7,2011-11-30,2011-11-30 12:00:00,2011-11-29 16:00:00,"AM"
10.1,2011-10-21,2011-10-21 12:00:00,2011-10-20 17:00:00,"AM"
9.7,2011-10-13,2011-10-13 12:00:00,2011-10-12 17:00:00,"AM"
10.8,2011-10-13,2011-10-13 12:00:00,2011-10-12 17:00:00,"AM"
10.7,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.4,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.1,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.7,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-06-29,2011-06-29 12:00:00,2011-06-28 17:00:00,"MID"
10.1,2011-12-12,2011-12-12 12:00:00,2011-12-11 16:00:00,"AM"
10.1,2011-12-09,2011-12-09 12:00:00,2011-12-08 16:00:00,"MID"
10.2,2012-02-07,2012-02-07 12:00:00,2012-02-06 16:00:00,"MID"
10.2,2011-12-16,2011-12-16 12:00:00,2011-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
10.3,2011-12-14,2011-12-14 12:00:00,2011-12-13 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-12-08,2011-12-08 12:00:00,2011-12-07 16:00:00,"MID"
10.2,2011-12-12,2011-12-12 12:00:00,2011-12-11 16:00:00,"AM"
9.5,2011-12-02,2011-12-02 12:00:00,2011-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2012-02-29,2012-02-29 12:00:00,2012-02-28 16:00:00,"MID"
9.1,2011-12-05,2011-12-05 12:00:00,2011-12-04 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-12-06,2011-12-06 12:00:00,2011-12-05 16:00:00,"MID"
9.7,2011-12-09,2011-12-09 12:00:00,2011-12-08 16:00:00,"MID"
9.1,2011-12-13,2011-12-13 12:00:00,2011-12-12 16:00:00,"AM"
10.5,2012-02-24,2012-02-24 12:00:00,2012-02-23 16:00:00,"MID"
9.8,2011-12-16,2011-12-16 12:00:00,2011-12-15 16:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-12-13,2011-12-13 12:00:00,2011-12-12 16:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2012-02-13,2012-02-13 12:00:00,2012-02-12 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-12-06,2011-12-06 12:00:00,2011-12-05 16:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-12-12,2011-12-12 12:00:00,2011-12-11 16:00:00,"AM"
10.7,2012-02-24,2012-02-24 12:00:00,2012-02-23 16:00:00,"AM"
10.1,2011-12-09,2011-12-09 12:00:00,2011-12-08 16:00:00,"MID"
9.6,2011-12-05,2011-12-05 12:00:00,2011-12-04 16:00:00,"AM"
9.8,2011-12-05,2011-12-05 12:00:00,2011-12-04 16:00:00,"AM"
10.2,2011-12-08,2011-12-08 12:00:00,2011-12-07 16:00:00,"MID"
10,2011-12-08,2011-12-08 12:00:00,2011-12-07 16:00:00,"MID"
11,2011-12-14,2011-12-14 12:00:00,2011-12-13 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-12-02,2011-12-02 12:00:00,2011-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
10.1,2011-12-06,2011-12-06 12:00:00,2011-12-05 16:00:00,"MID"
10.7,2011-12-14,2011-12-14 12:00:00,2011-12-13 16:00:00,"AM"
9.4,2011-12-02,2011-12-02 12:00:00,2011-12-01 16:00:00,"AM"
9.9,2011-12-13,2011-12-13 12:00:00,2011-12-12 16:00:00,"AM"
10.4,2012-03-02,2012-03-02 12:00:00,2012-03-01 16:00:00,"AM"
10.5,2012-02-06,2012-02-06 12:00:00,2012-02-05 16:00:00,"MID"
```

Comment: Providing example data as to what `x10NoOutliers` is would help.

Comment: Specifically the output from `head` and `str` would be useful.

Comment: I added the data set for you.  It's also curious that the expression used for the ylab is not displayed.

Comment: Also, this set of points shows up as in TimeOfDay group NA.  There are no NA's in the whole data set, let alone this group: [code]     "Concentration","ExecutionDate","iExecutionDate","pExecutionDate","TimeOfDay"
    9.3,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"PM"
    8.7,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"MID"
    9.7,2011-12-27,2011-12-27 12:00:00,2011-12-26 16:00:00,"MID"
[code]

Comment: I think the underlying issue here is that boxplots are typically made with a _discrete_ x axis scale (as you did using `factor` in your first plot), but ggplot considers dates to be a _continuous_ scale. I don't think you have have it both ways. You'll have to use the first version and then manually label only the days you want on the x axis in whatever "pretty" way you decide to go.

Comment: @joran, Well, that stinks.  What is interesting to me is that using the scale_x_date axis scale, I get NAs.  When I don't use that scale, I don't get NAs.  I'll have to investigate why.  I could possibly live with the funky grouping if the NA group was not there.

Comment: @joran, Typically, yes, but not necessarily. You can make a boxplot that is positioned along a continuous scale but whose data is based on a grouping on that scale. See my answer.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Nice! I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your example data, I assumed that the different date columns should be POSIXct's and the TimeOfDay is a factor (neither of which could be assumed from the format you gave).

I don't know why you are getting `NA`'s, I can not reproduce that. Possibly, it is because you are using `ggplot2-0.8.9` and I'm using `ggplot2-0.9.0` (I can tell by your arguments to `scale_x_date` which changed between those versions.

The problem with the incorrect boxplot groupings, though, is due to your specification of the `group` aesthetic; it should be `group=interaction(factor(ExecutionDate),TimeOfDay)`. You want it grouped by both of those.  Also, in the second one, you have your `x` mapped to `iExecutionDate` where in the first it is mapped to a transformation of `ExecutionDate`. Note that your `geom_smooth` does quite different things in those two cases as well. In the first, it "smooths" within each day and just connects the dots; in the second it smooths across time.

If you do change to version 0.9.0, you will need to change your `scale_x_date` specification.

```
ggplot(x10NoOutliers, aes(x=iExecutionDate, y=Concentration)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group=interaction(factor(ExecutionDate),TimeOfDay),
                     fill=TimeOfDay),
                 outlier.colour = "blue") +
    geom_smooth(aes(group = TimeOfDay, colour = TimeOfDay ) ) +
    scale_x_datetime(name = "Execution Date", 
                     breaks=date_breaks(width="1 week"),
                     labels = date_format()) +
    scale_y_continuous(expression( "Concentration,"~frac( "ng" , mu*"l" ) )) +
    opts(title = "Boxplot of Concentration by Execution Date and Time of Day",
         axis.text.x = theme_text( size = 7 , angle = -90 , hjust = 0 ) )
```

[image]

Note also that by putting the labels in the scale declarations, you get the proper expressions interpreted.

Also, an exactly reproducible version of your data (using `dput()`) is:

```
x10NoOutliers <-
structure(list(Concentration = c(8, 8.2, 7.5, 8.6, 7.9, 8.4, 
7.6, 8.4, 7.5, 8.7, 7.9, 7.8, 8.9, 8.6, 7.9, 7.6, 8.2, 8.6, 8.9, 
8.8, 8.4, 8.5, 7.8, 8, 8, 7.6, 9.2, 8.1, 7.5, 8.4, 8.3, 7.2, 
8.7, 8.2, 7.7, 8.2, 8.6, 8.9, 7.6, 8.5, 8.5, 8.1, 8.3, 8.8, 8.3, 
9.2, 7.7, 8.5, 7.7, 8.6, 8.8, 9, 9.1, 9, 9.2, 7.8, 8, 7.6, 7.7, 
8.9, 8, 8.9, 9.7, 8.7, 8.1, 8.5, 8.7, 8.5, 9.3, 8.5, 9.1, 7.6, 
8.7, 9, 9.2, 8.7, 9, 7.8, 7.8, 7.9, 9.7, 8.9, 9.4, 8.1, 9.6, 
9.4, 9, 8.4, 9.7, 8.4, 7.5, 8.7, 8.6, 7.8, 10.4, 8.5, 8.2, 8.5, 
8.8, 8.7, 7.6, 8.5, 8.2, 8.8, 8.5, 9.1, 8.3, 9.1, 8.6, 8.8, 8.6, 
8.5, 9.8, 9.3, 8.9, 9.5, 7.7, 8.5, 8.5, 7.9, 8.2, 7.7, 8.6, 8.9, 
8.3, 8.2, 8.8, 8.9, 8.3, 8.3, 9.9, 8.2, 8, 8.6, 8.4, 8.3, 8.9, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.7, 7.6, 8.6, 8.3, 8.1, 7.8, 8, 8.6, 7.9, 8.1, 9, 
8.2, 8.1, 8.4, 8.3, 8.2, 9, 8.8, 8, 8, 8.8, 7.8, 7.9, 9.2, 8.7, 
7.6, 8.6, 8.2, 7.8, 7, 8.2, 8.5, 8.3, 8.4, 8.8, 7.8, 7.9, 8.7, 
8.6, 7.8, 7.3, 8.1, 8.3, 8.9, 8.6, 8.6, 8.3, 8.3, 8.6, 8.4, 8.3, 
8.2, 8.7, 7.3, 9.4, 8.2, 8.9, 9.3, 8.6, 8.6, 7.9, 11.8, 7.9, 
8.5, 9.9, 8.2, 7.6, 8.3, 8.9, 9.8, 8.7, 9.2, 11.6, 9.9, 8.4, 
10, 9, 9.5, 8.1, 8.4, 7.8, 7.5, 7.8, 7.4, 8.8, 7.1, 8.2, 8.8, 
8.6, 7.8, 8.7, 8.3, 8, 9.5, 7.5, 8.3, 8.8, 9.3, 8.1, 8.3, 7.9, 
8, 9.9, 8.7, 8.7, 9.1, 9.2, 9, 8, 9, 8.8, 8, 10.1, 7.8, 9.3, 
9, 9.2, 9.9, 9.5, 9.1, 9.6, 9.9, 9.8, 9.2, 9.2, 10.5, 9.4, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.6, 9.9, 9.5, 10.3, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.9, 10.4, 9.2, 9.4, 
10.3, 9.4, 10.2, 9.2, 9.1, 10.6, 9.2, 9.1, 9.8, 10, 9.2, 9.3, 
10, 9.3, 9.4, 9.6, 10.3, 9, 10.6, 9.1, 10.7, 9.5, 13, 9.9, 9.1, 
10.1, 9.7, 9.3, 10.5, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 10.5, 10.5, 9, 10, 10.3, 
9.8, 10, 10.6, 8.8, 9.3, 10.2, 8.9, 9.5, 10.9, 11.5, 9.1, 9.4, 
9.7, 8.7, 9.9, 8.9, 10.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.2, 9.7, 10.2, 9.2, 9.5, 
11, 8.8, 9.6, 10, 10, 10.4, 10.6, 10.1, 9.4, 9, 10.7, 9.7, 9, 
9.8, 10.2, 9.9, 10, 10.2, 9.4, 9.4, 9.7, 10, 9.7, 9.9, 10.7, 
10.1, 9.7, 10.8, 10.7, 10.4, 10.1, 10.7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.1, 
10.1, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 9.5, 10.2, 9.5, 9.8, 9.1, 9.8, 9.7, 9.1, 
10.5, 9.8, 9.4, 10.2, 9.9, 10, 10.7, 10.1, 9.6, 9.8, 10.2, 10, 
11, 9.9, 10.1, 10.7, 9.4, 9.9, 10.4, 10.5), ExecutionDate = structure(c(1305788400, 
1291017600, 1290153600, 1292486400, 1297843200, 1290153600, 1289376000, 
1284620400, 1289289600, 1289203200, 1284447600, 1287039600, 1288940400, 
1288854000, 1288681200, 1284447600, 1284706800, 1284534000, 1284620400, 
1284620400, 1284361200, 1284706800, 1284447600, 1284534000, 1284361200, 
1284534000, 1284706800, 1284534000, 1284447600, 1284361200, 1284361200, 
1284706800, 1284447600, 1287558000, 1284706800, 1284361200, 1284534000, 
1284706800, 1284534000, 1284706800, 1288249200, 1284447600, 1284447600, 
1284102000, 1284534000, 1288162800, 1286953200, 1284102000, 1287558000, 
1284447600, 1284706800, 1288162800, 1287471600, 1284534000, 1284102000, 
1284447600, 1284447600, 1284447600, 1286780400, 1284620400, 1284447600, 
1287385200, 1286521200, 1284706800, 1284534000, 1286521200, 1284102000, 
1287558000, 1286434800, 1284534000, 1288162800, 1284534000, 1284706800, 
1284102000, 1288076400, 1284534000, 1284534000, 1284447600, 1284447600, 
1284534000, 1307602800, 1284447600, 1287990000, 1287126000, 1286348400, 
1284620400, 1286348400, 1287558000, 1312441200, 1302678000, 1302591600, 
1314687600, 1311058800, 1307516400, 1309244400, 1294214400, 1299225600, 
1299139200, 1297843200, 1291795200, 1299657600, 1299139200, 1292486400, 
1301986800, 1299139200, 1297670400, 1299052800, 1292486400, 1296806400, 
1296201600, 1301900400, 1291795200, 1295942400, 1291708800, 1291622400, 
1292400000, 1299052800, 1298966400, 1291622400, 1290585600, 1301900400, 
1301554800, 1300172400, 1295942400, 1291276800, 1301468400, 1299657600, 
1294041600, 1291276800, 1293609600, 1301295600, 1300690800, 1300431600, 
1293436800, 1290585600, 1290153600, 1295856000, 1298880000, 1293004800, 
1299830400, 1300431600, 1299571200, 1295596800, 1295510400, 1300345200, 
1299830400, 1292918400, 1299571200, 1299484800, 1289376000, 1290153600, 
1291017600, 1289894400, 1300258800, 1298275200, 1292313600, 1300172400, 
1291968000, 1295337600, 1298016000, 1299484800, 1295337600, 1291881600, 
1294646400, 1291190400, 1290153600, 1289289600, 1291017600, 1289980800, 
1294387200, 1292918400, 1294300800, 1299484800, 1292832000, 1299830400, 
1299744000, 1292572800, 1291190400, 1299225600, 1299744000, 1291881600, 
1299657600, 1310972400, 1312441200, 1307084400, 1312441200, 1289548800, 
1289462400, 1291190400, 1292572800, 1291881600, 1307084400, 1313650800, 
1313564400, 1309244400, 1314860400, 1313046000, 1305270000, 1306998000, 
1306998000, 1314601200, 1314601200, 1302505200, 1314342000, 1310713200, 
1305097200, 1310713200, 1312354800, 1310626800, 1314255600, 1314255600, 
1312873200, 1309158000, 1312354800, 1308812400, 1310540400, 1310454000, 
1312268400, 1308726000, 1305010800, 1306911600, 1311750000, 1304924400, 
1310367600, 1304492400, 1306911600, 1306393200, 1315897200, 1311750000, 
1314255600, 1308726000, 1304492400, 1313737200, 1312786800, 1311663600, 
1308294000, 1311577200, 1310108400, 1306306800, 1304406000, 1304060400, 
1312786800, 1303110000, 1302850800, 1308207600, 1311577200, 1302764400, 
1309935600, 1308121200, 1311318000, 1315810800, 1309849200, 1311231600, 
1311058800, 1307689200, 1309417200, 1315810800, 1315551600, 1322035200, 
1327478400, 1327651200, 1317020400, 1322812800, 1321862400, 1321603200, 
1320652800, 1319007600, 1316674800, 1320390000, 1322553600, 1317106800, 
1319698800, 1317020400, 1326873600, 1320390000, 1317020400, 1319785200, 
1320825600, 1323417600, 1322035200, 1326355200, 1319612400, 1319526000, 
1316070000, 1323849600, 1324368000, 1318834800, 1323331200, 1322035200, 
1317279600, 1320044400, 1321516800, 1317106800, 1319094000, 1319612400, 
1318575600, 1318402800, 1322553600, 1319526000, 1320652800, 1320652800, 
1319526000, 1320303600, 1323676800, 1316502000, 1325836800, 1324972800, 
1318921200, 1324022400, 1316674800, 1322467200, 1322467200, 1321948800, 
1323072000, 1324540800, 1319698800, 1318921200, 1317279600, 1318834800, 
1316415600, 1316674800, 1322640000, 1318575600, 1320912000, 1317193200, 
1317193200, 1316588400, 1319094000, 1316070000, 1324972800, 1316674800, 
1319526000, 1321948800, 1318834800, 1320303600, 1316070000, 1317106800, 
1318921200, 1323763200, 1320217200, 1319612400, 1323158400, 1321603200, 
1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1325232000, 
1315897200, 1317193200, 1321862400, 1324454400, 1322640000, 1319180400, 
1319785200, 1309330800, 1319698800, 1321344000, 1320739200, 1324972800, 
1309330800, 1321430400, 1309330800, 1322640000, 1319180400, 1318489200, 
1318489200, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 
1309330800, 1309330800, 1309330800, 1323676800, 1323417600, 1328601600, 
1324022400, 1323849600, 1323331200, 1323676800, 1322812800, 1330502400, 
1323072000, 1323158400, 1323417600, 1323763200, 1330070400, 1324022400, 
1323763200, 1329120000, 1323158400, 1323676800, 1330070400, 1323417600, 
1323072000, 1323072000, 1323331200, 1323331200, 1323849600, 1322812800, 
1323158400, 1323849600, 1322812800, 1323763200, 1330675200, 1328515200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), iExecutionDate = structure(c(1305831600, 
1291060800, 1290196800, 1292529600, 1297886400, 1290196800, 1289419200, 
1284663600, 1289332800, 1289246400, 1284490800, 1287082800, 1288983600, 
1288897200, 1288724400, 1284490800, 1284750000, 1284577200, 1284663600, 
1284663600, 1284404400, 1284750000, 1284490800, 1284577200, 1284404400, 
1284577200, 1284750000, 1284577200, 1284490800, 1284404400, 1284404400, 
1284750000, 1284490800, 1287601200, 1284750000, 1284404400, 1284577200, 
1284750000, 1284577200, 1284750000, 1288292400, 1284490800, 1284490800, 
1284145200, 1284577200, 1288206000, 1286996400, 1284145200, 1287601200, 
1284490800, 1284750000, 1288206000, 1287514800, 1284577200, 1284145200, 
1284490800, 1284490800, 1284490800, 1286823600, 1284663600, 1284490800, 
1287428400, 1286564400, 1284750000, 1284577200, 1286564400, 1284145200, 
1287601200, 1286478000, 1284577200, 1288206000, 1284577200, 1284750000, 
1284145200, 1288119600, 1284577200, 1284577200, 1284490800, 1284490800, 
1284577200, 1307646000, 1284490800, 1288033200, 1287169200, 1286391600, 
1284663600, 1286391600, 1287601200, 1312484400, 1302721200, 1302634800, 
1314730800, 1311102000, 1307559600, 1309287600, 1294257600, 1299268800, 
1299182400, 1297886400, 1291838400, 1299700800, 1299182400, 1292529600, 
1302030000, 1299182400, 1297713600, 1299096000, 1292529600, 1296849600, 
1296244800, 1301943600, 1291838400, 1295985600, 1291752000, 1291665600, 
1292443200, 1299096000, 1299009600, 1291665600, 1290628800, 1301943600, 
1301598000, 1300215600, 1295985600, 1291320000, 1301511600, 1299700800, 
1294084800, 1291320000, 1293652800, 1301338800, 1300734000, 1300474800, 
1293480000, 1290628800, 1290196800, 1295899200, 1298923200, 1293048000, 
1299873600, 1300474800, 1299614400, 1295640000, 1295553600, 1300388400, 
1299873600, 1292961600, 1299614400, 1299528000, 1289419200, 1290196800, 
1291060800, 1289937600, 1300302000, 1298318400, 1292356800, 1300215600, 
1292011200, 1295380800, 1298059200, 1299528000, 1295380800, 1291924800, 
1294689600, 1291233600, 1290196800, 1289332800, 1291060800, 1290024000, 
1294430400, 1292961600, 1294344000, 1299528000, 1292875200, 1299873600, 
1299787200, 1292616000, 1291233600, 1299268800, 1299787200, 1291924800, 
1299700800, 1311015600, 1312484400, 1307127600, 1312484400, 1289592000, 
1289505600, 1291233600, 1292616000, 1291924800, 1307127600, 1313694000, 
1313607600, 1309287600, 1314903600, 1313089200, 1305313200, 1307041200, 
1307041200, 1314644400, 1314644400, 1302548400, 1314385200, 1310756400, 
1305140400, 1310756400, 1312398000, 1310670000, 1314298800, 1314298800, 
1312916400, 1309201200, 1312398000, 1308855600, 1310583600, 1310497200, 
1312311600, 1308769200, 1305054000, 1306954800, 1311793200, 1304967600, 
1310410800, 1304535600, 1306954800, 1306436400, 1315940400, 1311793200, 
1314298800, 1308769200, 1304535600, 1313780400, 1312830000, 1311706800, 
1308337200, 1311620400, 1310151600, 1306350000, 1304449200, 1304103600, 
1312830000, 1303153200, 1302894000, 1308250800, 1311620400, 1302807600, 
1309978800, 1308164400, 1311361200, 1315854000, 1309892400, 1311274800, 
1311102000, 1307732400, 1309460400, 1315854000, 1315594800, 1322078400, 
1327521600, 1327694400, 1317063600, 1322856000, 1321905600, 1321646400, 
1320696000, 1319050800, 1316718000, 1320433200, 1322596800, 1317150000, 
1319742000, 1317063600, 1326916800, 1320433200, 1317063600, 1319828400, 
1320868800, 1323460800, 1322078400, 1326398400, 1319655600, 1319569200, 
1316113200, 1323892800, 1324411200, 1318878000, 1323374400, 1322078400, 
1317322800, 1320087600, 1321560000, 1317150000, 1319137200, 1319655600, 
1318618800, 1318446000, 1322596800, 1319569200, 1320696000, 1320696000, 
1319569200, 1320346800, 1323720000, 1316545200, 1325880000, 1325016000, 
1318964400, 1324065600, 1316718000, 1322510400, 1322510400, 1321992000, 
1323115200, 1324584000, 1319742000, 1318964400, 1317322800, 1318878000, 
1316458800, 1316718000, 1322683200, 1318618800, 1320955200, 1317236400, 
1317236400, 1316631600, 1319137200, 1316113200, 1325016000, 1316718000, 
1319569200, 1321992000, 1318878000, 1320346800, 1316113200, 1317150000, 
1318964400, 1323806400, 1320260400, 1319655600, 1323201600, 1321646400, 
1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1325275200, 
1315940400, 1317236400, 1321905600, 1324497600, 1322683200, 1319223600, 
1319828400, 1309374000, 1319742000, 1321387200, 1320782400, 1325016000, 
1309374000, 1321473600, 1309374000, 1322683200, 1319223600, 1318532400, 
1318532400, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 
1309374000, 1309374000, 1309374000, 1323720000, 1323460800, 1328644800, 
1324065600, 1323892800, 1323374400, 1323720000, 1322856000, 1330545600, 
1323115200, 1323201600, 1323460800, 1323806400, 1330113600, 1324065600, 
1323806400, 1329163200, 1323201600, 1323720000, 1330113600, 1323460800, 
1323115200, 1323115200, 1323374400, 1323374400, 1323892800, 1322856000, 
1323201600, 1323892800, 1322856000, 1323806400, 1330718400, 1328558400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), pExecutionDate = structure(c(1305763200, 
1290988800, 1290124800, 1292457600, 1297814400, 1290124800, 1289347200, 
1284595200, 1289260800, 1289174400, 1284422400, 1287014400, 1288915200, 
1288828800, 1288656000, 1284422400, 1284681600, 1284508800, 1284595200, 
1284595200, 1284336000, 1284681600, 1284422400, 1284508800, 1284336000, 
1284508800, 1284681600, 1284508800, 1284422400, 1284336000, 1284336000, 
1284681600, 1284422400, 1287532800, 1284681600, 1284336000, 1284508800, 
1284681600, 1284508800, 1284681600, 1288224000, 1284422400, 1284422400, 
1284076800, 1284508800, 1288137600, 1286928000, 1284076800, 1287532800, 
1284422400, 1284681600, 1288137600, 1287446400, 1284508800, 1284076800, 
1284422400, 1284422400, 1284422400, 1286755200, 1284595200, 1284422400, 
1287360000, 1286496000, 1284681600, 1284508800, 1286496000, 1284076800, 
1287532800, 1286409600, 1284508800, 1288137600, 1284508800, 1284681600, 
1284076800, 1288051200, 1284508800, 1284508800, 1284422400, 1284422400, 
1284508800, 1307577600, 1284422400, 1287964800, 1287100800, 1286323200, 
1284595200, 1286323200, 1287532800, 1312416000, 1302652800, 1302566400, 
1314662400, 1311033600, 1307491200, 1309219200, 1294185600, 1299196800, 
1299110400, 1297814400, 1291766400, 1299628800, 1299110400, 1292457600, 
1301961600, 1299110400, 1297641600, 1299024000, 1292457600, 1296777600, 
1296172800, 1301875200, 1291766400, 1295913600, 1291680000, 1291593600, 
1292371200, 1299024000, 1298937600, 1291593600, 1290556800, 1301875200, 
1301529600, 1300147200, 1295913600, 1291248000, 1301443200, 1299628800, 
1294012800, 1291248000, 1293580800, 1301270400, 1300665600, 1300406400, 
1293408000, 1290556800, 1290124800, 1295827200, 1298851200, 1292976000, 
1299801600, 1300406400, 1299542400, 1295568000, 1295481600, 1300320000, 
1299801600, 1292889600, 1299542400, 1299456000, 1289347200, 1290124800, 
1290988800, 1289865600, 1300233600, 1298246400, 1292284800, 1300147200, 
1291939200, 1295308800, 1297987200, 1299456000, 1295308800, 1291852800, 
1294617600, 1291161600, 1290124800, 1289260800, 1290988800, 1289952000, 
1294358400, 1292889600, 1294272000, 1299456000, 1292803200, 1299801600, 
1299715200, 1292544000, 1291161600, 1299196800, 1299715200, 1291852800, 
1299628800, 1310947200, 1312416000, 1307059200, 1312416000, 1289520000, 
1289433600, 1291161600, 1292544000, 1291852800, 1307059200, 1313625600, 
1313539200, 1309219200, 1314835200, 1313020800, 1305244800, 1306972800, 
1306972800, 1314576000, 1314576000, 1302480000, 1314316800, 1310688000, 
1305072000, 1310688000, 1312329600, 1310601600, 1314230400, 1314230400, 
1312848000, 1309132800, 1312329600, 1308787200, 1310515200, 1310428800, 
1312243200, 1308700800, 1304985600, 1306886400, 1311724800, 1304899200, 
1310342400, 1304467200, 1306886400, 1306368000, 1315872000, 1311724800, 
1314230400, 1308700800, 1304467200, 1313712000, 1312761600, 1311638400, 
1308268800, 1311552000, 1310083200, 1306281600, 1304380800, 1304035200, 
1312761600, 1303084800, 1302825600, 1308182400, 1311552000, 1302739200, 
1309910400, 1308096000, 1311292800, 1315785600, 1309824000, 1311206400, 
1311033600, 1307664000, 1309392000, 1315785600, 1315526400, 1322006400, 
1327449600, 1327622400, 1316995200, 1322784000, 1321833600, 1321574400, 
1320624000, 1318982400, 1316649600, 1320364800, 1322524800, 1317081600, 
1319673600, 1316995200, 1326844800, 1320364800, 1316995200, 1319760000, 
1320796800, 1323388800, 1322006400, 1326326400, 1319587200, 1319500800, 
1316044800, 1323820800, 1324339200, 1318809600, 1323302400, 1322006400, 
1317254400, 1320019200, 1321488000, 1317081600, 1319068800, 1319587200, 
1318550400, 1318377600, 1322524800, 1319500800, 1320624000, 1320624000, 
1319500800, 1320278400, 1323648000, 1316476800, 1325808000, 1324944000, 
1318896000, 1323993600, 1316649600, 1322438400, 1322438400, 1321920000, 
1323043200, 1324512000, 1319673600, 1318896000, 1317254400, 1318809600, 
1316390400, 1316649600, 1322611200, 1318550400, 1320883200, 1317168000, 
1317168000, 1316563200, 1319068800, 1316044800, 1324944000, 1316649600, 
1319500800, 1321920000, 1318809600, 1320278400, 1316044800, 1317081600, 
1318896000, 1323734400, 1320192000, 1319587200, 1323129600, 1321574400, 
1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1325203200, 
1315872000, 1317168000, 1321833600, 1324425600, 1322611200, 1319155200, 
1319760000, 1309305600, 1319673600, 1321315200, 1320710400, 1324944000, 
1309305600, 1321401600, 1309305600, 1322611200, 1319155200, 1318464000, 
1318464000, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 
1309305600, 1309305600, 1309305600, 1323648000, 1323388800, 1328572800, 
1323993600, 1323820800, 1323302400, 1323648000, 1322784000, 1330473600, 
1323043200, 1323129600, 1323388800, 1323734400, 1330041600, 1323993600, 
1323734400, 1329091200, 1323129600, 1323648000, 1330041600, 1323388800, 
1323043200, 1323043200, 1323302400, 1323302400, 1323820800, 1322784000, 
1323129600, 1323820800, 1322784000, 1323734400, 1330646400, 1328486400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TimeOfDay = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AM", "MID", "PM"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Concentration", "ExecutionDate", 
"iExecutionDate", "pExecutionDate", "TimeOfDay"), row.names = c(NA, 
-409L), class = "data.frame")
```